# node.js and require module - how it works?

Tags: node.js

I build a server with node.js that use some require var.

For example, I have `server.js` file with the next var: `var s3 = require('s3')`

In addition, `server.js` contains some functions with callbacks. for example:

```
app.post('upload', function (req, res){
   s3.upload(req.path);
}

app.post('delete', function (req, res){
   s3.delete(req.path);
}
```

As I know, the application will run the request asynchronous.

My question is about s3: because I have only one s3 object (which defined by the require)- it will limit the asynchronous and concurrency of node.js. For example, the server get 10 requests from different clients. It can serve all, but it will limit by the s3 object which is common to all requests.

this is how node.js works? should I define collection of `s3` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to define multiple s3 objects. Since node is effectively single threaded you won't gain anything from that - only one instruction will be executed at a time anyway.

Let's see how a hypothetical `s3.method` is implemented (assuming here that s3 refers to amazon s3):

1. Your code calls `s3.method`
2. `s3.method` does some computation locally then
3. `s3.method` sends a request and awaits the response (or does some other form of input-output).
4. your code handles the response.

1,2 and 4 are relatively fast operations compared to 3 (unless you do some heavy lifting in 1,2 or 4, but let's assume that's not the case).

So what node does when reaching operation 3 is yielding the control to some other part of your code while it's waiting for response. This waiting is handled by node runtime and OS-level event system. When the response arrives, it's handler is queued for execution and executed as soon as the control is yield back to node runtime and it's the first on the queue.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand: If I upload 2 files: one of 10 GB, and one of 20GB - which are really heavy operation - what node.js would do? this happens before it awaits for the response - it happens when the server sends the request.

Comment: It's a simplification, but behind the scenes s3 would start the upload on the operating system level, leaving the node runtime free to execute some other client code.

Comment: Or even simpler, at some point node tells operating system: "hey, send/write this thing there and tell me when you get something back". OS takes over and node can carry on executing other parts of your app.

Comment: OK, so as you say the responsibility of the upload process go to the OS level. I would be happy if you have information about what happens in the OS level. it would open one or some connection to s3? How it is determined?

Comment: It's an (uneducated) guess but id say each call to s3 object opens new connection to s3, which is then pooled and reused.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that s3 will wait for the action to finish: it's a common way in node.js to start running something and provide callback which will be called when the command finishes. Mainly it's designed so to optimize I/O actions and optimize for low CPU using applications.

Comment: So you mean that s3 would open also some connections behind the scene?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about s3, you didn't tell me it:) It's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs main (event) loop runs in a single thread.

Which means pretty much all code you write is executed one at the time. Nodejs' is asynchronic for 'slow' functions, like (but not limited to!) database calls or other IO operations such as file manipulation.

So only one upload and delete request is handled at a single time, ,and only one s3 object is needed./